# Subset generated for subset.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S\subset \mathbb R^n$. Suppose that $S$ is not contained in any proper subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. Thus $\mathbb R S=\mathbb R^n$ and we may select a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ of $\mathbb R^n$ contained in $S$.

Why $v_1,\ldots,v_n\in S$  ?

Thank you all-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\forall v_1, \dots, v_n \in S$ these are linearly dependent. Then the linear subspace spanned by $S$ has dimension at most $n-1$, and $S$ is contained in a proper linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

But this contradicts your assumption on $S$, so there must exist $v_1, \dots, v_n \in S$ linearly independent, and these are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.